# Meteor user profile always undefined

Tags: meteor

I can't see any profile information on my users, any idea why?

server :

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
        {fields: {'profile': 1}});
});
Meteor.publish("allUsers", function () {
    //TODO: For testing only, remove this
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'profile': 1}});
});
```

client :

```
Meteor.autosubscribe(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('allUsers',null , function() { console.log(Meteor.users.find().fetch()) });
    Meteor.subscribe('userData', null, function() { console.log(Meteor.user())});
});

....

Accounts.createUser({email:email,password:password, profile: {name: name}},function(error){
    ...
});
```

My console output an object with only _id and emails for the first one and undefined for the second one.
The profile information (name in my case) seems to works because in my server.js I have a name validation that works fine :

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    if(options.profile.name.length<2)
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Please provide a name.");
    return user;
});
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem :

In the onCreateUser function , I need to add this the profile information from the options to the user object , so my function should looks like this instead :

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    if(options.profile.name.length<2)
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Please provide a name.");
    if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
    return user;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When using multiple subscriptions, only the [first subscription matters](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe). The second subscription, if containing the same collection is ignored because it conflicts with the first.

You could do this instead, though:

server:

```
var debugmode = false; //set to true to enable debug/testing mode
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
    if(debugmode) {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, fields: {'profile': 1}});
    }
    else
    {
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},{fields: {'profile': 1}});
    }
});
```

client:

```
Meteor.autosubscribe(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('userData', null, function() { console.log(Meteor.user()); console.log(Meteor.users.find({}).fetch());});
});
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the answer! But this still doesn't solve my problem as the user Profile data isn't returned in the log object, only the _id and emails

Answer (score 1):

Here is the workaround I am using, placed in ~/server/createAccount.js The issue I was having is that I would get errors where profile was undefined. This seems to fix things by creating the profile when the account is created.

Hope this is useful. Found it on a github issue comment, in the comment below:

```
// BUGFIX via https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1369 @thedavidmeister
// Adds profile on account creation to prevent errors from profile undefined on the profile page
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  user.profile = options.profile ? options.profile : {};
  return user;
});
```